Is it needed to check the signed-in status of a user when my middleware does it, using clerk?
I am building a simple app with NextJs and Clerk.
I set up the middleware to protect all routes but some.
import { clerkMiddleware, createRouteMatcher } from '@clerk/nextjs/server';

const isPublicRoute = createRouteMatcher(['/sign-in(.*)', '/sign-up(.*)']);

export default clerkMiddleware((auth, request) => {
  if (!isPublicRoute(request)) {
    auth().protect();
  }
});

export const config = {
  matcher: [
    // Skip Next.js internals and all static files, unless found in search params
    '/((?!_next|[^?]*\\.(?:html?|css|js(?!on)|jpe?g|webp|png|gif|svg|ttf|woff2?|ico|csv|docx?|xlsx?|zip|webmanifest)).*)',
    // Always run for API routes
    '/(api|trpc)(.*)',
  ],
};


After playing a bit with it, I was wondering: on my protected pages, do I need to check if the user is signed in ? (e.g. using useUser() hook)
Shouldn't it be check by the middleware ?
Do I still need to check it in case that could be bypassed?
Many thanks to anyone willing to teach me a bit about this.
Matthieu

No, this isn't necessary. Once you protect a route in middleware you cannot bypass that since it runs on every request.
In fact a scraper couldn't even know that a protected route exists without logging in unless you have a site map.

So yes you are good as long as Clerk behaves as it should.
However, if your concern is with security checkout security and privacy from the Clerk team.
